# Java - Pixel array not rendering from another class another class

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee, canvas, 2d-games

I am experimenting with game development in java. As of now, I can use the screen class to render to the Canvas of an image through pixel array. However, whenever I attempt to render to the canvas through the pixel array within the other class, it reads the pixels array's content. x y numbers and all but, does not render it to the canvas at all even though the other class extends the screen class (thus inheriting the pixels array and the x, y numbers).
What is causing this? How do I go about fixing it?

from the other class:

```
void origin(){

    if(x <= ax && y <= ay)
        pixels[ox + oy * width] = 0xff00ff;
    }
```

From the screen class:

```
void waves(){
    orga = new Organism(width, height);

    for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++){

            Color wacol = new Color(0, 0, u);
            int water = wacol.getRGB();

            pixels[x + y * width] = water;
            orga.origin();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the class isn't enough, it has to be hooked up to the screen in the same way as the pixel array that works.